# Can I extend my 30 days Schengen visa in Switzerland?

Tags: schengen, switzerland, visa-extensions

I am Filipina and I'm in Switzerland right now together with my sponsored, and my 30 days Schengen visa for housemaid will going to expire on Aug 25 '2014, Can I extend my visa till 31 of Aug 2014 from Switzerland? Where I can go to process my visa?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I don't think it's possible. Application for regular Schengen visas should be submitted at the consulate responsible for your place of residence and extension is only possible in very limited cases.

There might however be some Swiss visa available to you but it's unlikely to be practical. In any case, the relevant authorities would be the cantonal migration offices. [Here is a list, with addresses](https://www.bfm.admin.ch/content/bfm/en/home/die_oe/kontakt/kantonale_behoerden/adressen_kantone_und.html).