# Extension of Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland, visa-extensions

I am visiting my sister in **Switzerland**, my visa type C, my duration of stay 32 days 
for 30/Aug to 1/Oct.
I want to extend my stay 10 days more, is it possible? And if I can, where should I go to?
(it's still 7 days in my visa visit it end at 1/Oct i want to stay to 11/Oct ). What can I do? And what documents I need?
Could anyone please suggest if I would need a formal approval process from local canton office?

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: *[Can I extend my 30 days Schengen visa in Switzerland?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34595)* and *[How to extend my stay in the Schengen area at the end of my trip?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26589)*.